# Proper way to wrap prismajs findFirst on a model

Tags: typescript, prisma, volar

I need to replace the default findFirst function on a model to preparse a JSON value in my custom function. While I could use an extension, it doesn't allow me to convert the type of a field to a custom type, so I'll need to create my own wrapper function

I've tried below:

```
export const articleFindFirst = async findFirst(
        p: Parameters<typeof prismaClient.article.findFirst>[0]
) {
  console.log('where', p.where); // this works
//...
```

but problem is, when I'm calling from outside, it throws error of undefined

```
articleFindFirst({ where: { title: 'abc' }});
```

error show on visual code:

```
Type '{ title: string; }' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.
```

it also happen with other parameters like include, select

but building the project with tsc seems to build successfully.
does anyone know why? i do have volar overriding ts in place on my visual studio